# After rotating image I can't add a new image?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating mobile aplication with Apache Cordova and I have one div and two buttons(one to import picture, second for rotating picture). When I insert picture, picture shows inside div and I can replace it with another one, but if I rotate picture I can't import another one ?

```
var destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

$("#capture").click(function () {

        getPhoto(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);

    });

function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
    });
}

var cameraSuccess = function (imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('pic');
    image.src = imageData;
    return image.src;
}

var cameraError = function () {
    alert("Error");
}

 $("#left").click(function () {
        $("#pic").rotate(90);
    });
```

Comment: Where is the code for the rotation?

Comment: Is there any message in the console? What if you put a console.log("get photo now"); in the getPhoto() function just to see that it is being hit after an image rotation

Comment: First I get ""get photo now" but after rotating I don't get anything ...

Comment: maybe try bind the rotate click event. I dont know if that will fix it but i am not sure why it is not working either http://api.jquery.com/bind/